# My Wifi adapter not connect to wifi with linux mint 17

Tags: linux, wireless-networking, linux-mint

```
env:
linux mint 17.3
uname linux 3.19.0-32-generic#37~14.0.4.1-Ubuntu
adapter tp-link archerT2U
driver https://github.com/Myria-de/mt7610u_wifi_sta_v3002_dpo_20130916

command:
iwconfig:
ra0 Ralink STA ESSID:"" Nickname:"MT7610U_STA"
    Mode:Auto Frequency=2.412 GHz Bite Rate:1 Mb/s
    RTS thr:off Fragment thr:off
    Encryption key:off
    etc..

ifconfig:
ra0 was not found in this command

/proc/net/wireless:
status 0000
```

I tested whether the WiFi adapter could be connected to a WiFi even with a higher version of Linux, but it failed.
so I reverted linux to the current version and The driver has been rebuilt to the root directory
Like when it was connected before.
However, it has not been connected to wifi ever since the version was restored.

There was a question in a similar situation
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41234080/iwlist-scan-return-no-result-ra0
so I wrote the command to the terminal as root and
I tried to restart and try to connect, but it didn't work.

Comment: In case you aren't aware, support for 17.3 ended in April of this year.  If you don't update, you will be exposed to risks, and there won't be further updates of your software.  You may also encounter increasing problems with dependencies and incompatibilities if you try to do the maintenance manually.  Your test with a more recent release didn't solve the WiFi problem, but it will be an easier base from which to solve it because you will be getting drivers, libraries for dependencies, etc. from current repositories.  It will also be easier for other to replicate the problem.

Comment: @fixer1234 Thank you for your reply.I known mint17 ended the support.
So, after updating to the latest version of Mint 19 and trying to use the above driver, when I typed in the make command,an error occurred and I could not proceed to the next stage.I have no knowledge of C, so I do not know where to fix it. In addition, the driver's repository doesn't seem to be active more than a year ago,so I don't know what to do.